# Laravel 5.4 Authentication password reset redirect based on email address

Tags: laravel, email, redirect, authentication

I am involved in a web site using Laravel 5.4 and using the built-in authentication.

I have added a "Forgot Password" link that shows the ResetPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm which emails a password
reset link when submitted and then the ResetPasswordController@showResetForm redirects to the login page when submitted.

The problem I have is that we have two different Users - clients and admins. I have the ability to determine which is
which through the registered email address but I want the redirect following password reset be different for each type
(client = '/' and admin = '/admin').
How is this be done?

Comment: Are you using Auth to generate the reset url (token) or is your custom method?

Comment: I am using Auth to generate the token

Comment: Then you should build a custom one.
Check if the user is a client or an admin and then add a parameter to the route.
Here an example on how to start:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54664095/1076753

Comment: thanks. I will give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `ResetsPasswords` trait in your controller, you can create your own `redirectTo()` method which will be called to redirect the user :

```
// import the needed trait
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class YourResetPasswordController {
    // use the needed trait
    use ResetsPasswords;

    // override the method that redirects the user
    public function redirectTo()
    {
        if (auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
            return redirect('/admin');
        } else {
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it helped you :)